# jquery .on not working after converting from .live in ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code and fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/sunnyday195/VMDyL/1/) and i need to use the latest version of jquery which of course does not support .live. when i go to use .on the highlighting does not work. here is the js code:

```
 $("#input-service_date_leave, #input-service_date_return").datepicker({
    rangeSelect: true,
    beforeShow: customRange,
    onSelect: customRange,
});

function customRange(input) {
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_leave") {

        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").off();

        if (selectedDate != null) {
            $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_return") {

        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).parent().addClass("finalRow");
                $(".finalRow").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
           },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("finalRow");
                $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
            }
        });

        var selectedDate = $("#input-service_date_leave").datepicker("getDate");                
        if (selectedDate != null) {
            $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to use `.on()`?

Comment: sorry i left it in there. i've updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are mouseenter http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ and mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ events.

So, this should work for you (not tested):

```
$("#input-service_date_leave, #input-service_date_return").datepicker({
                                                                         rangeSelect: true,
                                                                         beforeShow: customRange,
                                                                         onSelect: customRange
});

function customRange(input)
{
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_leave")
    {

       $("#ui-datepicker-div td").off();

       if (selectedDate != null)
       {
           $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
       }
    }
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_return")
    {

       $("#ui-datepicker-div td").mouseenter(function ()
                                             {
                                                $(this).parent().addClass("finalRow");
                                                $(".finalRow").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                                                $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                                             }
                                 );
       $("#ui-datepicker-div td").mouseleave(function ()
                                            {
                                                $(this).parent().removeClass("finalRow");
                                                $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
                                            }
                                 );

    var selectedDate = $("#input-service_date_leave").datepicker("getDate");                
    if (selectedDate != null)
    {
        $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem like any mouse events are firing at all, i tried click hover etc.

Comment: try to use $(element).datepicker().mouseenter(...). I think it´s because the element isn´t a datepicker.

Comment: i'm surprised at how complicated it is to attach event handlers to this ui piece. i would have thought this stuff comes built in.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. use something like this:

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter.td","#ui-datepicker-div tr", function() {
                       //code here
                        });
```